# Loss of Contact

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm sorry to post this, I know it has been asked before but I have tried the previous solutions and nothing has seemed to work.

The problem that I'm having is that I use both didBeginContact and didEndContact to establish whether or not my sprite is touching the ground.

The sprite has a BOOL named **grounded** that determines this state. Basically I want to know if its on the ground when its touching a platform. The results that I am getting are a constant battle between establishing contact with the platform and then losing contact immediately, its very frustrating. Here's what I have so far:

```
-(Player *)createPlayer
{
    ...
    sprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:player.size];
    sprite.physicsBody.mass = 0.02;
    sprite.physicsBody.restitution = 0;
    sprite.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = playerCategory;
    sprite.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = platformCategory;
    sprite.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = platformCategory;
    sprite.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
    return sprite;
}
-(SKSpriteNode *)createPlatform
{
    SKSpriteNode *platform = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[SKColor grayColor] size:CGSizeMake(100,25)];
    platform.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:player.size];
    platform.dynamic = NO;
    platform.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = platformCategory;
    platform.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = playerCategory;
    platform.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory;
    return platform;
}

-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;

    if(contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.B.categoryBitMask)
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA;
        secondBody = contact.bodyB;
    }
    else
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB;
        secondBody = contact.bodyA;
    }
    if((firstBody.categoryBitMask & playerCategory) != 0)
    {
        Player *player = firstBody.node;
        if((secondBody.categoyBitMask & platformCategoy) != 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"Connection Established");
            player.grounded = YES;
        }
    }
}

-(void)didEndContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;

    if(contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.B.categoryBitMask)
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA;
        secondBody = contact.bodyB;
    }
    else
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB;
        secondBody = contact.bodyA;
    }
    if((firstBody.categoryBitMask & playerCategory) != 0)
    {
        Player *player = firstBody.node;
        if((secondBody.categoyBitMask & platformCategoy) != 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"Connection Lost");
            player.grounded = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically the end result of this looks like this when I examine the log:

- **Contact Established**
- **Contact Lost**
- **Contact Established**
- **Contact Lost**

Thank you in advance for any help you offer, I am completely stumped.

Comment: Maybe make your sprite much heavier.  Also, try turning off precise collision detection.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I just tried adjusting the weight of the sprite, but nothing seemed to work. the sprite itself is bouncing whenever it strikes the platform, even though its restitution is set at 0, which is why I keep losing contact, does anyone know how to make sure that the object does not bounce when it hits the platform?

Comment: You can try when the contact begin to set the velocity of the player to (0,0) in didBeginContact  

    [[player physicsBody] setVelocity:CGVectorMake(0, 0.0f)];

and replace the player on the top of the platform. All in didBeginContact

Comment: I didn't see this before.  I would set the platform restitution to 0.

Comment: I tried setting the velocity manually upon didBeginContact to `CGVectorMake(player.physicsBody.velocity.dx, 0)` but it still bounced. I thought that it might have been trying to correct overlapping issues so I tried to set the position to `CGPositionMake(player.position.x, platform.position.y+1)` but even that didn't work. I am pleased to say though that in the end setting the restitution of the platform to 0 did work. Although I am not entirely sure why, as from my understanding it should only effect the bounciness of the platform itself. Thank you very much once again for all of your help.

Answer (score -1):

```
-(void)didEndContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{

    uint32_t collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);

    if (collision != (playerCategory | platformCategory)) {
        SKNode *node = contact.bodyA.node;
        if (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == platformCategory) {
            node = contact.bodyB.node;
        }
NSLog(@"Connection Lost");
            player.grounded = NO;
    }
```

Comment: Explain what you changed in this code and how this is going to fix the problem. Just posting code without explanation isn't helpful.

Comment: Thank you once again, I just discovered the problem I was having with your code above. My code is now a lot shorter, the only thing I had to adjust as changing `if(collision != (playerCategory | platformCategory))` to `if(collision == (playerCategory | platformCategory))`. With that being said I am still having the same problem as before, where the NSLog prints: **Connection Established, Connection Lost, Connection Established, Connection Lost** which of course means that in the end the player is not grounded. Confirmed when I placed a call to the log during frame updates, printing it out.